# Missing dependency for method public void

Tags: java, html, http, jersey, jackson

I have this code:

```
@Path("/automation/devices")
@Singleton
public class DevicesWebService {
    private AppiumServerManager appiumServerManager;
    private AdbService adbService;
    private DevicesService deviceService;

    public DevicesWebService() {
        this(new AdbServiceLocal(), new AppiumServerManagerLocal());
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public DevicesWebService(AdbService adbService, AppiumServerManagerLocal AppiumServerManager) {
        this.adbService = adbService;
        this.appiumServerManager = AppiumServerManager;
    }


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessage() {
        return "welocme to devices web-service";
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    @Path("/acquireDevice/{device}/{port}")
    public Response acquireDevice(@PathParam("device") Device device, @PathParam("port") Integer port) throws
            Exception {
        try {
            deviceService.acquireDevice(device, port);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();

    }
//
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:9998/");
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server running");
        System.out.println("Visit: http://localhost:9998/automation/devices");
    }
}
```

My code fails in runtime with this exception:

```
Mar 20, 2016 12:37:51 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.m.mobileautomation.devices.webServices.DevicesWebService
  class com.m.mobileautomation.MobileAutomationWebService
Mar 20, 2016 12:37:51 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Provider classes found:
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
  class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper
Mar 20, 2016 12:37:51 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 05:39 AM'
Mar 20, 2016 12:37:52 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.m.mobileautomation.devices.webServices.DevicesWebService.acquireDevice(com.m.mobileautomation.devices.dataModel.Device,java.lang.Integer) throws java.lang.Exception at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.m.mobileautomation.devices.webServices.DevicesWebService.acquireDevice(com.m.mobileautomation.devices.dataModel.Device,java.lang.Integer) throws java.lang.Exception, annotated with POST of resource, class com.m.mobileautomation.devices.webServices.DevicesWebService, is not recognized as valid resource method.
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:172)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:264)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:246)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:92)
    at com.m.mobileautomation.devices.webServices.DevicesWebService.main(DevicesWebService.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

If i comment out `public Response acquireDevice` everything works.

I have tried to remove `` as well but still got an error:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.m.mobileautomation.devices.webServices.DevicesWebService.acquireDevice(com.m.mobileautomation.devices.dataModel.Device,java.lang.Integer) throws java.lang.Exception at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Method, public void com.m.mobileautomation.devices.webServices.DevicesWebService.acquireDevice(com.m.mobileautomation.devices.dataModel.Device,java.lang.Integer) throws java.lang.Exception, annotated with POST of resource, class com.m.mobileautomation.devices.webServices.DevicesWebService, is not recognized as valid resource method.
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:172)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:264)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:246)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:92)
    at com.waze.mobileautomation.devices.webServices.DevicesWebService.main(DevicesWebService.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Read the Javadoc for `@PathParam`, and it will tell you the requirements for using custom type parameters. Jersey doesn't know how to create `Device` from a String. But there are a few ways can allow Jersey to know how to create it.  See the javadoc

Comment: The @PathParam java doc only deals with params naming not the conversion from string to java object. I have followed this tutorial, what am i missing? http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/

Comment: Did you not read something about a static `fromString(String)` or `valueOf(String)` method or a constructor that accepts a String? Those are your options for your `Device` class, if you want to use it a parameter type for `@PathParam`.  You need to construct the `Device` from the string passed to any one of those three options

Comment: I will google it. Basically if I want to send the "device" using POST, i can send it only in the message body. right?

Comment: You are trying to use a `Device` as a method parameter for a `@PathParam`. That is the reason for the error. I explained how to fix it. Other than that it seems you are changing the subject, so I am not sure what is really the question

Comment: I didn't change the question. I want to fix this, but if it's more common to send Pojo in PUT as in the body - i will fix to that method now, and not fix the method parameter and then change to body object

Comment: If you want the `Device` to be the body of the request, it should not have `@PathParam`.

Comment: what is more common to do? param or body? or it doesn't matter

Comment: If you want it as a `@PathParam` that mean you want put the JSON in the URL. That is not common, and a bad idea. So put it in the body

Answer (score 2):

As @peeskillet  says, `@PathParam` should not be used to pass objects as it is more commonly used to specify a variable you would use to identify the resource/object your operating on (for instance in your case I would maybe use `acquireDevice/{deviceId}/{port}` if say, the id had any significance beforehand).

Using it like you do now can also really obfuscate stuff for you when you're testing or need to see what's going on in the log - think of how an entry with a json stuck in the middle will look in your applications access log.

If you're looking to pass objects you should definitely use the request's body - also notice Jackson (I saw you tagged it so I'm assuming that's what you use with Jersey) has to know how to deserialize that object as well or you will fail on that too.